# Download & Email Case Details using templates

Tags: email-template

I would like to know if it is possible to download case details or email the case details based on email templates to other users(call center users) on the case details layout.

Conga Composer is one of the appexchange tool which helps. But still I am not happy with Conga composer tool . Guys please let me know if there is any good tool to fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Conga Composer would be a silver bullet on this requirement.  If there is anything we can do to improve your experience, please don't hesitate to reach out to me directly @CongaPete

Peter

Peter Terhune
Director

Comment: We have an requirement to edit the email templates without downloading. is it possible to do it Conga composer ?